# Combining two projects and get a single .sln file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I want to combine two projects into one i.e. image and audio steganography with a single .sln file. How do I connect them? I'm using Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 1):

You can find an answer here:

[How do I merge two different Visual Studio solutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603744/how-do-i-merge-two-different-visual-studio-solutions)

Or simply right click on the solution Add existing project (or Add existing item) and select the solution to be merged

Answer (score 1):

What the other guy said about opening one solution and adding an existing project sounds pretty good.  If for some reason you open your projects and don't see a solution in your Solution explorer, you can always create a blank solution:

[image: Blank Solution]

And then add the projects to it.
Go to File->Add->Existing Project.

[image: Add Existing Project]

Select a project.

[image: Project1]

Select another project.

[image: Project2]

Your new solution:

[image: New Solution]

**Remember:** If you're merging projects that have websites or web services, you need to select "Add Existing Website" and choose the folder that the website / web service is in. (:

Hope that helps!

Comment: how do i merge these solution files

Comment: I added a few more pictures to show the process of adding existing projects into your solution. (:

Comment: thanx a lot...but what is the procedure to merge them

Comment: I don't think I understand what you want to happen when you merge.  Typically, when people want to merge solutions, they want to move all the projects in two solutions into a single solution.  Is there something else you are trying to achieve?

Comment: okay...can you tell me code for connecting 2 forms in .csproj file? just like we do .Show() in .vbproj